# how to add two bootstrap class properties in html table tag?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my Html code. I want to add two class properties of bootstrap in tag `<table>`, eg(table-bordered & table-striped).

I want to use this both class properties 
in table tag.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>anmol</td>
        <td>america</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The basic rule is: A HTML tag can have at most one id in the `id` attribute but there can be many classes (separated by space) in the `class` attribute. In your case, `table-bordered` and `table-striped` are the 2 class names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
```

You can add as many classes as you want. Don't forget to add the base class .table

Answer (score 0):

```html
After  doing some research in google i am able to use those both 
class properties by doing this..

<table class="table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>anmol</td>
        <td>america</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done just use it like `<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>`. You can also use CSS if you want to use some different color.

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Wasim</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
```

Bootstrap has many class for table. You can add more than one class to the element.